# Calculating a value with JS and Storing that value in database

Tags: javascript, laravel-5.8

I'm calculating 2 value with js:

```
$('input').keyup(function(){ // run anytime the value changes
    var firstValue  = Number($('#user_send_fund_amount').val());
    var secondValue = Number($('#fixed_amount').val());
    document.getElementById('user_receive_fund_amount').value = firstValue * secondValue ;
document.getElementById('user_receive_fund_amount').setAttribute('readOnly', true);
document.getElementById('user_receive_fund_amount').removeAttribute('readOnly');`
```

and trying to store this value:

```
<form  method="POST" class="form-register" action="{{ route('order.store') }}">
 @csrf
   <input id="user_send_fund_amount" type="number" class="form-control"
     name="user_send_fund_amount" required>
    <input type="number" value="{{$receive->buy}}" class="form-control"
        id="fixed_amount" hidden>
    <input type="number" class="form-control" id="user_receive_fund_amount" name="user_receive_fund_amount"/>
</form>
```

[image: I'm getting null value whenever I try to input those JS value]
My question is: **How can I store this Calculated value in DB?**

Comment: Do you mean store in a database? Store with local or session storage? Etc.

Comment: @justDan Yes store in database

Comment: What kind of database are you using?

Comment: @KingGary using **phpmyadmin**

Comment: I think your input being readonly could be a problem

Comment: phpmyadmin is not a database - it is a tool to manage MySQL database

Comment: I dont think that there is a problem here, your code works in the jsFiddel editor -> https://jsfiddle.net/6nvepfxg/, Check is network all the params are going after the function call and form-submit

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just make this change! and Hope this will work:
`$("input[name=user_receive_fund_amount]").val(firstValue*secondValue);`

Answer (score 0):

You can use JQuery to calculate values as below code.

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() { 
  $('#user_send_fund_amount').change(function(){
      var firstValue  = parseInt($('#user_send_fund_amount').val()) | 0;
      var secondValue = parseInt($('#fixed_amount').val()) | 0;
  $('#user_receive_fund_amount').val(firstValue * secondValue);
  });
});
</script>

<form  method="POST" class="form-register" action="{{ route('order.store') }}">
 @csrf
   <input id="user_send_fund_amount" value="0" type="number" class="form-control"
     name="user_send_fund_amount" required>
    <input type="hidden" value="{{$receive->buy}}" class="form-control"
        id="fixed_amount">
    <input type="number" readonly class="form-control" id="user_receive_fund_amount" name="user_receive_fund_amount"/>
</form>
```

Comment: Still can't store that calculated value. Getting null

Comment: check my modification in the same post

Answer (score -2):

Your code has a syntax error in this line:

```
document.getElementById('user_receive_fund_amount').value = firstValue * secondValue ;});
```

Remove the `;})` from end. So the line becomes:

```
document.getElementById('user_receive_fund_amount').value = firstValue * secondValue;
```